# How to apply a sequential number pattern in Pathauto?

Tags: path-aliases

If the path name is same, I want to show display as below.

I want:

```
example.com/blog/path001
example.com/blog/path002
example.com/blog/path003 ...
```

currently:

```
example.com/blog/path
example.com/blog/path-1
example.com/blog/path-2 ...
```

But I don't know how to apply these patterns?
What should I do?

Comment: For what it is worth, note that the dashes are generally accepted as being more SEO friendly. If that matters at all.

Answer (score 5):

You need an additional module for this – [Serial Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial).

> Unlike Drupal's built-in auto-increment node ID, which is global and
>   shared by nodes belonging to all content types, serial fields are
>   managed per content type (D6) / entity (D7). For example, the serial
>   field of an Invoice instance will generate a unique sequential number
>   (starting at 1, then 2, etc.) exclusively for Invoice instances.

You then can use Serial Field + Token + Path Auto - to create serial numbers in urls, for example: http://www.example.com/issue/10 (where 10 is a type scope serial number).